# How to show the current user using ASP MVC and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005. I am using also Entity Framework with Code First Method.

I have an interface for the LOG ON (connection) which it is related to my base where i have a USER table (contain Login + password).

I am just want to show the Current User which is logged. So, I created a ViewModel Class for the User but i didn't get any result.
This is what I tried to do in my Controller :

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
        {


            var user = new UserViewModel();
            user.Nom_User = this.User.Identity.Name;
            ViewData["UserDetails"] = user;
            return View();
        }
```

and this what I add in the master page :

```
    <% var User = ViewData["UserDetails"] as MvcApplication2.ViewModels.UserViewModel; %>
 Hello : <%: User.Nom_User  %>!
```

When I execute, I have this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that you placed this code in your MasterPage. This means that it will run for **every** view.

But you have set the `ViewData["UserDetails"]` only inside the `LogOn` action. So when you navigate to some other action (such as the Home/Index action for example) it will bomb because there's nothing inside this `ViewData["UserDetails"]` and of course this `User` variable which you declared in your MasterPage will be null.

I would recommend you using a child action for that.

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult LogedInUser()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    var user = new UserViewModel();
    user.Nom_User = User.Identity.Name;
    return PartialView(user);
}
```

and in your MasterPage:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("LogedInUser", "Account"); %>
```

or if you prefer:

```
<%= Html.Action("LogedInUser", "Account") %>
```

And finally you could have the corresponding `LogedInUser.ascx` partial that will be strongly typed to your view model:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<UserViewModel>" 
%>

<% if (Model != null) { %>
    <div>Hello : <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Nom_User) %></div>
<% } %>
```

Phil Haack blogged about child actions in more details [`here`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I follow your instructions but there is an Compilation error concerning <% Html.RenderAction("Account", "LogedInUser") %>

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a trailing `;`. It should be: `<% Html.RenderAction("Account", "LogedInUser"); %>`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you,,,but there is always this error :
The controller for path '/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Comment: In the same Line : <%= Html.Action("Account", "LogedInUser") %>

Comment: I just find the solution. The parametres of Action should be like this : <%= Html.Action("LogedInUser","Account") %>

Comment: You are perfectly right. The first parameter is the action name. Thanks for spotting this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `session`

```
Session["user"]=this.User.Identity.Name;
```

and in view you can get user name with `<% var User =Session["user"]%>` or you can directly use:
`<% var User =this.User.Identity.Name;%>`